# From $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(0)$ derive $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)\mathrm{d}x=f(a)$

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta, substitution

Firstly, apologies for abusing the notation by placing the Dirac measure inside an integral for which I was told that this should not be done from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460037/why-is-displaystyle-int-x-inftyx-infty-fx-deltax-mathrmdx) asked by me. But given the circumstances, I have no choice.

This is almost a word by word copy of the derivation given on page 2 of [this](http://www.nada.kth.se/~annak/diracdelta.pdf) paper on the Dirac delta:

Starting from $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(0)$ and by changing variables and noting that $\delta(x)$ is symmetric we can derive a more general formula:

$$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \begin{align}\color{red}{\tag{1}}\quad f(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) \delta(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\color{blue}{\tag{2}}\quad f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi+x) \delta(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\color{#F80}{\tag{3}}\quad f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) \delta(\xi - x) \, \mathrm{d}\xi\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\color{#080}{\tag{4}}\quad f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) \delta(x-\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi\end{align}$$

$\color{red}{(1)}$ was the only part I understood. So does this mean the change of variables was such that $x \rightarrow \xi$?

Going from part $\color{#F80}{(3)}$ to $\color{#080}{(4)}$ can only mean that $\delta(\xi - x)=\delta(x-\xi)$. Why is this true? I know that $\delta(x)$ is symmetric but still don't get why this makes $\delta(\xi - x)=\delta(x-\xi)$?

Now, lastly and *most* **importantly**, I have no idea how they went from $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$ and would be very grateful if anyone could explain/show all the intermediate steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$, substitute $\xi\mapsto\xi-x$.

Comment: @robjohn Okay, I understand that part now, thanks robjohn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details of the steps:

$\color{red}{(1)}$ to $\color{blue}{(2)}$, function substitution $f(t)\mapsto f(t+x)$.

$\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$, substitute $\xi\mapsto\xi-x$.

$\color{#F80}{(3)}$ to $\color{#080}{(4)}$, $\delta$ is even; i.e. $\delta(-x)=\delta(x)$.

Comment: Was there something else?

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on $\color{red}{(1)}$ to $\color{blue}{(2)}$. Can you show all the steps for the function substitution $f(x)\mapsto f(x + \xi)$? As I don't understand why you can just substitute for $f$ and not $\delta$. In other words why does the substitution not change
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ to
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+\xi) \delta(x+\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi$? Thanks again.

Comment: @BLAZE: $(1)$ is true for all functions in place of $f$. Suppose we used $g(t+x)=f(t)$, then we get $$g(x)= f(0)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi)\,\delta(\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\xi+x)\,\delta(\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi$$ Now just rename $g$ to $f$

Comment: Why is $\color{red}{(1)}$ true for all functions in place of $f$?

Comment: That is the definition of $\delta$. If we only knew that $f(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\delta(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ for one particular function, that wouldn't be very useful. There would be lots of functions $\delta$ satisfy that.

Comment: The reason I'm confused is because for $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$, making the substitution $\xi\mapsto\xi-x$ results in 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi+x) \delta(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) \delta(\xi - x) \, \mathrm{d}\xi$ but for $\color{red}{(1)}$ to $\color{blue}{(2)}$, you only substitute $f(x)\mapsto f(x+\xi)$ for $f(x)$ but $\delta(x)$ is left alone, why is that?
I thought an integral substitution must be carried out on the entire integrand $f(x)$ and $\delta(x)$?

Comment: @BLAZE: that is because in $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$ we are substituting the variable $\xi$ and leaving $f$ alone, whereas in $\color{red}{(1)}$ to $\color{blue}{(2)}$ we are substituting the function $f$ and leaving $\xi$ alone.

Comment: For $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$, we can't be leaving $f$ alone as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi+x) \delta(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) \delta(\xi - x) \, \mathrm{d}\xi$: The function $f$ argument changed from $f(\xi+x)$ to $f(\xi)$. Also, in $\color{red}{(1)}$ to $\color{blue}{(2)}$ do you mean we are leaving $\delta$ alone instead of $\xi$?

Comment: No. In $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to $\color{#F80}{(3)}$, we are leaving $f$ and $\delta$ alone and only changing $\xi$ everywhere we see it to $\xi-x$. We never do anything to $\delta$ in any step. $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function at all points of the proof.

Comment: Okay, you've been a massive help on this question. Just one _final_ question: What do you mean by "we see it to $\xi-x$"?

Comment: That phrase is being taken out of context. What the whole phrase means is that "everywhere we see $\xi$, we change it to $\xi-x$".

Comment: Thank you for your time, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot expect a correct proof of a formula which makes no sense within the formalism at your disposal: There is no function $x\mapsto\delta(x)$ such that for "all" $f$ one has  $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\>\delta(x)\>dx=f(0)\ .\tag{1}$$

Instead we should view $(1)$ as  shorthand for the following mental process: We consider a sequence of functions $\delta_n:\> x\mapsto \delta_n(x)\geq0$ with $\int_{\mathbb R}\delta_n(x)\>dx=1$ and $\delta_n(x)\equiv0$ when $|x|\geq{1\over n}$. For such a sequence $(\delta_n)_{n\geq1}$ one has
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\>\delta_n(x)\>dx=f(0)\tag{2}$$
for all suitable $f$. Now replace the $\delta_n$ by the translated functions $\delta_{a.n}: \>x\mapsto \delta_n(x-a)$. Ordinary substitution gives
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\>\delta_n(x-a))\>dx=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x'+a)\>\delta_n(x')\>dx'\ .$$
According to $(2)$, applied to the function $g(x'):=f(x'+a)$, we get that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\>\delta_n(x-a))\>dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} g(x')\>\delta_n(x')\>dx'=g(0)=f(a)\ .$$
The "shorthand version" of the last formula is
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\>\delta(x-a))\>dx=f(a)\ .$$

Comment: I believe that the confusion was not because $\delta$ is a distribution, but because of the substitutions. The same substitutions that were bothering the OP would be there for any even $\delta_n$ in place of $\delta$, and the questions asked in the comments to my answer would most likely be the same. However, I could be mistaken.